# How to search / filter the linked assets list in inDesign to see a list of assets by format. eg. PSD, PNG, JPEG etc?

Tags: adobe-indesign

Is it possible to search / filter the linked assets list in inDesign to see a list of assets by format. eg. PSD, PNG, JPEG etc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you can search the links panel. You can kind of set filters, you can add additional panel options and then sort by those different options.

Click on the top 3 bars for the Links Window and open Panel Options.

[image: Panel Options]

Then add or remove the different options you want shown in the Links Window.

[image: Format Option]

In this example, you can now filter by file format.

Comment: If your InDesign file is package, then you can search the folder on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have saved all your linked images in a single folder, you can navigate to that folder in Finder or Explorer (right-click on one of the links in your Links panel and select "Find in ....") and search/filter there.